# What's the time zone of the timestamp of LANDSAT Images?

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, google-earth-engine, landsat, landsat-8

**I am using google earth engine just to print the timestamp here of LANDSAT Image. I am using the geometry of a part of Chennai which is in India.**

```js
// Filtering Data with Date and Geometry
var Data2 = LANDSAT.filterBounds(geometry).filterDate('2013-04-09', '2014-04-10');
// Printing Timestamp
print('LANDSAT Metadata', Data2.first().date());
Map.centerObject(geometry, 8);
Map.addLayer(geometry,{color: 'FF0000'},"Chennai");
```

**My question what exactly the printed time does indicate (with respect to UTC (GMT) or Local Time Zone (IST) ).**

just in case if you need the import

**IMPORTS:**

```js
var LANDSAT = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA"),
geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[80.26491619216495, 13.08801893465061],
      [80.26422954665713, 13.077652181027775],
      [80.28002239333682, 13.08166516962143]]]);
```

**I am using google earth engine only to print the timestamp here of LANDSAT Image and not anyway related to my question.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Landsat documentation](https://landsat.usgs.gov/how-can-i-find-acquisition-time-image), "Landsat data acquisition times are expressed in Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) standard."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know about timezone of the 3 Hourly TRMM Data Timestamp too?

Comment: I believe those are also in GMT.

Comment: Can I have a source so that I can include it in my presentation?

Comment: @PrasadThota have you tried looking for a source on your own? Before posting a question here it is expected that you tried to find an answer yourself.

Comment: @Kersten Yes, I have searched in TRMM Data Users Handbook. But I couldn't find it.